# Увеличение фото при нажатии

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Вот сайт: http://www.richrol.com внизу при нажатии на фото оно увеличивается. Как сделать также но не так убого что б было?) а то там тормозит и какие то лишние символы отображаются. Только, пожалуйста, с оглядкой на то, что фото будет много. Благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[как обычно](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/).
А уж будет ли тормозить, и будут ли лишние символы — зависит от вас.

Comment: Елена, балодарю! Все сделал за 3 минуты, все работает! Пожалуйста, ответьте мне на следующий вопрос: http://hashcode.ru/questions/286855/javascript-rак-сделать-обычную-не-3д-карусель-фото
он тоже не сложный для Вас, по видимому)

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен чистый JavaScript, то лучше подойдет библиотека [highslide.js](http://highslide.com/). Как ее внедрить можно посмотреть [тут](https://stud-work.ru/uvelichenie-kartinki-pri-klike-prostoj-sposob-s-pomoshchyu-highslide-js)